# How to create relative path from absolute path in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, relative-path, pwd

I am in this directory:

```
/home/michal/project/test/my-utils/rel/0.1.0
```

and I would like to get the relative path to /home/michal/project/ in Linux shell:

```
../../..
```

I've tried something with sed but I did not succeeded in creating the regular expression. E.g. one of the attempts:

```
pwd | sed -e "s/.*project\///g" | sed -e "s/[^\/]+/../g"
```

Any tips how to do it?

Comment: Maybe just `sed 's,^/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*,../../..,'`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does not work in an expected way:
$ pwd | sed 's,^/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*,../../..,'
../../../project/test/my-utils/rel/0.1.0
I would like to have a relative path to /home/michal/project/ directory. Something without knowing how many subdirectories I have.

Comment: So it's more like "Determine how far I need to climb back up my directory tree until I get to the desired folder, that number is how many `../` I need to concatenate for my answer"

Comment: This seems a little bit like an XY problem; what's wrong with just using the absolute path `/home/michal/project`? You can get that with `${path%%/test/*}`. (I'm assuming you know that `test` is the "root" subdirectory.)

Comment: Try `awk -F/ '{f=0;for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {if($i!="project" && f==0) {printf "../"} else {if (f==0) {printf "../";f=1} else {printf $i "/"}}}}'  <<< "${PWD}"`

Comment: @kvantour Yes, it could be a duplicate. Funny, I've spent at least 10 minutes trying to find something like that, because this basic question has had to be answered somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the command `realpath`:

```
realpath --relative-to=${PWD} /home/michal/project/
```

from the help page:

> --relative-to=FILE       print the resolved path relative to FILE

Comment: +1 learned new command could have found in `man readlink` "see also" but should have known that we could do relative path with it

Comment: That's it and without regular expressions! Thanks!